# Django Form Automatically select first option if only one choice available

Tags: python, django, forms

Is there an easy way to select the first option of a dropdown in a Django form, in cases where there is only one option available?

With easy I mean a solution that doesn't require defining an own widget, which would be quite repetitive to change in all our (model) forms.

*Update because it seems like the initial question was unclear:*

I want the initital option only to be selected if there is one option available. And the the way to do that is non-obvious to me, if the options are foreign key references to another model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
     name = CharField(...)

class Post(models.Model):
    category = ForeignKey(Category)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
    [...]
```

Now I want the `category` field in the `PostForm` to be autoselected to the first category, if only one instance is present in the database and be `--------` if there a two or more categories

Comment: post some code. What about to use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial)?

Answer (score 2):

What about using this :

```
Your_Dropdown = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=your choises, initial='FIRST_OPTION')
```

As shown in documentation: [Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any explanation is required, have a look at following code

```
post_type_choices = (
    ('article', 'article'),
    ('tip', 'tip'),
    ('snippet', 'snippet'),
)


class Post(models.Model):
    post_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=post_type_choices,default='article')
```

Comment: Well, this works if you have predefined options. But how to do that, if the choices are actually foreign key references to another model? Maybe my question should have been more clear. I'll update it

Comment: add code snippets for models in your updated question

Answer (score 1):

I did it in the get_form() like this:

```
    def get_form(self, form_class=form_class):
        form = super(WPWeekSubjectCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        ....
        subjects = Subject.objects.filter(
            schoolyear=schoolyear,
            pk__in=subject_bearings,
            lesson__teachers=teacher
        ).order_by('abbreviation').distinct()

        form.fields['subject'].queryset = subjects
        if subjects.count() == 1:
            form.fields['subject'].initial = subjects.first()
    
        return form
```